# Найти элемент в списке по слову

Tags: python, tkinter

Есть список:

```
spisok = ['колбаса=1', 'мясо=2', 'суп=3']
```

Нужно узнать, в каком элементе списка spisok есть слово 'мясо'. А потом нужно чтобы переменная element была равна числу, стоящее после знака '=' элемента, который мы только что нашли(в котором есть слово 'мясо'.

Comment: А почему вы использовали список, a  не словарь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Советую пользоваться не списком, а словарём.

```
spisok = {'колбаса': 1, 'мясо': 2, 'суп': 3}
```

Тогда можно обратиться к ключу, например `spisok['мясо']` выдаст 2.

В вашем случае со списком можно разве что так. Предположим, что нам надо найти "мясо".

```
spisok = ['колбаса=1', 'мясо=2', 'суп=3']
for i in spisok:
    text = i.split('=')
    if text[0] == 'мясо':
        number = text[1]
```

То есть делим по символу "=" и проверяем.

Comment: `dict(map(lambda x: x.split('='), spisok))`